# How to re-render directive with new template in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm doing a simple web project, but I got an issue with Angular directive. It can not re-render the html, it only render at the first time. this is my code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/Jc9wNoMrMlwAbRDsoviU?p=preview

```
app.directive('dyTemplate', ['$compile',function($compile) {
    var getTemplate = function(contentType) {
      templateMap = {
        1: '<div><a href="" ng-click="changeTemplate(2)"> Change to Template 2</a></div>',
        2: '<div><a href="" ng-click="changeTemplate(3)"> Change to Template 3</a></div>',
        3: '<div><a href="" ng-click="changeTemplate(1)"> Change to Template 1</a></div>'
      };
      return templateMap[contentType];
    }
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
        // default load template
        element.html(getTemplate(1));
        element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())(scope));
        scope.changeTemplate = function(templateId) {
          element.html(getTemplate(templateId));
          element.replaceWith($compile(element.html())(scope));
        }
      }
    }
  }
]);
```

Comment: can you setup a plunker

Comment: Yep, this is plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jc9wNoMrMlwAbRDsoviU?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

You're using `element.replaceWith()`, which the first time removes the element from the DOM, but then later calls doesn't change the DOM, since `element` isn't in it any more.

I also suspect you're overcomplicating things by using `$compile`. In most situations it's better (because it's simpler) to just use the `template` option in a directive. Angular then handles the compilation for you. In the template, you can use `{{}}` interpolation, call functions, and change what's being displayed using `ngIf` if you need to, just like any compiled template, and there isn't usually a need to be manually compiling or tinkering with the DOM.

An example of this can be seen at http://plnkr.co/edit/17empWUlkfR904qtI2Oe?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('myapp',[]); 
app.directive('dyTemplate', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'EA',
    scope:{},
    template: '<div><a href="" ng-click="showNextTemplate()"> Change to Template {{nextTemplateId()}}</a></div>',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.templateId = 1;

      scope.nextTemplateId = function() {
        var templateMap = {
          1: 2,
          2: 3,
          3: 1
        };
        return templateMap[scope.templateId];
      };

      scope.showNextTemplate = function() {
        scope.templateId = scope.nextTemplateId();
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Michal. This is just simple code for testing. In my project the template is more complicated than that. If element is not exist any more, I think I need to find new way to change the template.